# EncodedImage failing to work on actual phone

Tags: codenameone

I am facing a problem while using encodedImage. When a user logins into the app, the first form after successful login has an image. And the image is causing me issues upon retrieving it.

When the user captures an image in the app, I convert it to a base64 string which I send to the server. The code for that is:

```
ImageIO img = ImageIO.getImageIO();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.save(et, out, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();
String userImage64 = Base64.encodeNoNewline(ba);
```

et is the captured image. So I store the string userImage64 in the server.

When I retrieve the base64, I decode it and convert it to an EncodedImage. The code is:

```
String url = new JSONObject(result.getResponseData()).getString("photo");
byte[] b = Base64.decode(url.getBytes());
Image icon = EncodedImage.create(b);
```

When I am on the simulator, everything flows smoothly. The images display and everything works very well.

My issue is, when I put the app on an android device, it doesn't work. It shows me a toast of successful login and just stops there. So i did some debugging and realized that issue is with the three lines of converting from base64 to image. When I comment out the three lines, everything works very well. Where could I be going wrong?

**EDIT**
Below is the code I use to capture a photo:

```
String i = Capture.capturePhoto();
        if (i != null) {
            try {
                final Image newImage = Image.createImage(i);
                Image roundedMask = Image.createImage(rich.minScreensize() / 4, rich.minScreensize() / 4, 0xff000000);
                Graphics gra = roundedMask.getGraphics();
                gra.setColor(0xffffff);
                gra.fillArc(0, 0, rich.minScreensize() / 4, rich.minScreensize() / 4, 0, 360);

                Object masked = roundedMask.createMask();

                cropImage(newImage, rich.minScreensize() / 4, rich.minScreensize() / 4, et -> {

                    if (editing) {
                        try {
                            ImageIO img = ImageIO.getImageIO();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            img.save(et, out, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
                            byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();
                            userImage64 = Base64.encodeNoNewline(ba);
                            et = et.applyMask(masked);

                            logoimage.setIcon(et);
                            ///removed unnecessary code
                            logoimage.getComponentForm().revalidate();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {

                        }
                    } else {
                        et = et.applyMask(masked);

                        logoimage.setIcon(et);
                    }

                });

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.p("Error loading captured image from camera", Log.ERROR);
            }
        }
```

Inside there is code I use to crop the photo and that is code is:

```
private void cropImage(Image img, int destWidth, int destHeight, OnComplete<Image> s) {

    Form previous = getCurrentForm();
    Form cropForm = new Form("", new LayeredLayout());

    Label toobarLabel = new Label("New Holder", "Toolbar-HeaderLabel");
    cropForm.setTitleComponent(toobarLabel);

    Toolbar mainToolbar = new Toolbar();
    mainToolbar.setUIID("ToolBar");
    cropForm.setToolbar(mainToolbar);

    Label moveAndZoom = new Label("Move and zoom the photo to crop it");
    moveAndZoom.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0xffffff);
    moveAndZoom.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(CENTER);
    moveAndZoom.setCellRenderer(true);
    cropForm.setGlassPane((Graphics g, Rectangle rect) -> {
        g.setColor(0x0000ff);
        g.setAlpha(150);
        Container cropCp = cropForm.getContentPane();
        int posY = cropForm.getContentPane().getAbsoluteY();

        GeneralPath p = new GeneralPath();
        p.setRect(new Rectangle(0, posY, cropCp.getWidth(), cropCp.getHeight()), null);
        if (isPortrait()) {
            p.arc(0, posY + cropCp.getHeight() / 2 - cropCp.getWidth() / 2,
                    cropCp.getWidth() - 1, cropCp.getWidth() - 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        } else {
            p.arc(cropCp.getWidth() / 2 - cropCp.getHeight() / 2, posY,
                    cropCp.getHeight() - 1, cropCp.getHeight() - 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        }
        g.fillShape(p);
        g.setAlpha(255);
        g.setColor(0xffffff);
        moveAndZoom.setX(0);
        moveAndZoom.setY(posY);
        moveAndZoom.setWidth(cropCp.getWidth());
        moveAndZoom.setHeight(moveAndZoom.getPreferredH());
        moveAndZoom.paint(g);
    });

    final ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer();
    viewer.setImage(img);

    cropForm.add(viewer);
    cropForm.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToRightBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_CROP, e -> {
        previous.showBack();
        s.completed(viewer.getCroppedImage(0).
                fill(destWidth, destHeight));
    });
    cropForm.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToLeftBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_CANCEL, e -> previous.showBack());
    cropForm.show();

}
```

Comment: This is probably an issue of size. A picture from the camera is HUGE by default and can crash your phone. How do you capture? What code do you use for that?

Comment: I have added the code I use.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong. Can you get the base64 image taken from the device and try to debug it in the simulator? Does a picture taken on the device work there?
Can you decode the base64 and look at the physical file so we can see if there's a problem with it?

Comment: A picture taken from the phone doesn't work on the simulator. I got the base64 string and used an online decoder and it decoded correctly. On second thought, without using URLImage is there a way of saving the decoded image using my approach and i store it to storage the way the URLImage.createToStorage() works and the device just retrieves it from storage?

Comment: I didn't use URLImage because I am not saving my images anywhere. I just store the base64 on my server and retrieve it when required.

Comment: You can use ConnectionRequest [downloadImageToStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#downloadImageToStorage-java.lang.String-) and the other variants there. If you can decode the image provide the decoded version here, maybe there's something suspicious about it.